# Finding center of Siemens star

Tags: python, opencv

I have to find the center of a [Siemens star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siemens_star). (A Siemens star is a standard image used in camera calibration.)

Very easy for a human, but I can't figure out which (preferably OpenCV) methods to use. I'm using Python.

[image]

I've tried using edge detection, I thought I could get the edge contours, then make some equations of lines, then see where those lines intersected. But I get some messy lines with messiness at the edges, and the contours are all disjoint (or perhaps I don't understand them...). Here are the contours found with this code:

```
from OpenCVX import cvx2

filepath = 'img.jpg'
img = cvx2.imread(filepath, 0)

ret, thresh = cvx2.threshold(img, 127, 255, 0)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cvx2.findContours(thresh, cvx2.RETR_TREE, cvx2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cvx2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (255,255,255), 3)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Anyway, are there any tricks to solve such a problem? Assume I'm a n00b..

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried

Comment: @Leva7: Added more details

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing. It's not perfectly robust but it may be good enough for now. Just taking the sum of the cols and rows gives either a peak or a dip - finding the maximum or the minimum near some guessed position gives the center.

```
sum_cols, sum_rows = np.sum(img, axis=0), np.sum(img, axis=1)
```

[image]

Unfortunately there are some minority cases where this doesn't work. The min or max at the center flips from a min to a max wildly as the star rotates. In the middle of that flip it is neither a min nor a max for some finite distance around the guessed center of the image. Feel free to offer better suggestions if you have any...